# Using a variable for a url in form action tag html file

Tags: django, forms, view

How would I use a variable in place of a string for form action? I have tried the following and have gotten an error.

URLS

```
url(r'^newrole', ModelCreateView.as_view(model = Role, model_url = 'role-new', page_name = 'Role'), name='role-new'),
url(r'^newmember', ModelCreateView.as_view(model = Member, model_url = 'member-new', page_name = 'Member'), name='member-new'),
```

View

```
class ModelCreateView(CreateView):

model_url = None
page_name = None
template_name = 'create_model.html'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse(model_url)

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(ModelCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['page_name'] = self.page_name
    return context
```

Both of these report the errors below respectively

```
 <form action="{% url {{model_url}} %}" method="POST">
 <form action="{% url model_url %}" method="POST">
```

Errors

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{model_url}}' from '{{model_url}}'. The syntax of 'url'changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.

'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs
```

Is there a way to do this without using a series of if statements inside the html file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `reverse`. You can read more about it in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(ModelCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['page_name'] = self.page_name
    context['model_url'] = reverse("name of the url goes here")
    return context
```

Then in your template you don't use the url template tag. You just use the variable.

```
<form action="{{ model_url }}" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right:

```
<form action="{% url model_url %}" method="POST">
```

You just don`t pass model_url variable into template context, you need to add one line:

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(ModelCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['page_name'] = self.page_name
    context['model_url'] = self.model_url # this line added
    return context
```